# Is it possible to ng-repeat incrementing $index by an arbitrary number?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I currently have a template:

```
        <div class="choice-pair" ng-repeat="choicePair in pastChoices track by $index" ng-init="p1Result = getP1Result(choicePair); choiceNum = $index + 1;">
            <div class="turn-count cell"><strong>{{choiceNum}}</strong></div>
            <div class="p1 cell" ng-class="{win: p1Result === 1, lose: p1Result === -1, draw: p1Result === 0}"><strong>{{choicePair[0]}}</strong></div>
            <div class="p2 cell" ng-class="{win: p1Result === -1, lose: p1Result === 1, draw: p1Result === 0}"><strong>{{choicePair[1]}}</strong></div>
        </div>
```

pastChoices is an array containing sub arrays of length 2 for example:

```
[['A', 'B'],['B', 'C'],['A', 'A'],['C', 'A']]
```

but due to a need to change the data storage type on the server I have had to flatten this structure so that pastChoices are now inlined:

```
['A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A']
```

is it possible for me to make a small change to the template to get it to iterate over the new pastChoices format by incrementing by 2, so then I can select out choice pairs like:

```
        <div class="choice-pair" ng-repeat="choices in pastChoices track by $index" ng-init="p1Result = getP1Result(pastChoices[$index], pastChoices[$index + 1]);">
            <div class="turn-count cell"><strong>{{$index + 1}}</strong></div>
            <div class="p1 cell" ng-class="{win: p1Result === 1, lose: p1Result === -1, draw: p1Result === 0}"><strong>{{pastChoices[$index]}}</strong></div>
            <div class="p2 cell" ng-class="{win: p1Result === -1, lose: p1Result === 1, draw: p1Result === 0}"><strong>{{pastChoices[$index + 1]}}</strong></div>
        </div>
```

this looks like it will get me the data I want, except that it will iterate over every element of the pastChoices array, where as I want it to effectively skip odd numbered elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not using `choices`, you can just limit the amount of results by half the total in your ng-repeat:

```
<div class="choice-pair" ng-repeat="choices in (pastChoices | limitTo: pastChoices.length / 2 ) track by $index ">
    <div class="turn-count cell"><strong>{{($index * 2) + 1}}</strong></div>
    <div class="p1 cell" ng-class="{win: p1Result === 1, lose: p1Result === -1, draw: p1Result === 0}"><strong>{{pastChoices[($index * 2)]}}</strong></div>
    <div class="p2 cell" ng-class="{win: p1Result === -1, lose: p1Result === 1, draw: p1Result === 0}"><strong>{{pastChoices[($index * 2) + 1]}}</strong></div>
</div>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo

This will clearly fail if your array is not an even length.